# Как списку li вместо стандартного маркера сделать ромб?

Tags: html, css

Как списку li вместо стандартного маркера сделать ромб? Смотрел свойство list-style-type, но там квадраты и прозрачный круг, нужен ромб. Я так понимаю его нужно задать псевдоэлементом after? Но как тогда его можно сверстать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transform: translate(0, -50%) scaleY(1.5) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Элемент 1</li>
  <li>Элемент 2</li>
  <li>Элемент 3</li>
  <li>Элемент 4</li>
</ul>
```